# How to make functions work concurrently with aiogram?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio, telegram

I'm working on a Python program that utilizes the asyncio library along with aiogram for Telegram bot development. The program consists of two functions: image_detection() and handle_messages().

The image_detection() function uses OpenCV and pyautogui to capture the screen and perform template matching to detect a specific image. If the image is found, it sends the captured image to a Telegram user using the aiogram library.

On the other hand, the message_hander() function handles incoming messages from Telegram users and replies with a confirmation message.

The problem I'm facing is that these two functions do not work concurrently. When image_detection() is executing, message_handler() doesn't reply to user's message.

I have tried using asyncio.gather() to run both functions concurrently, but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. How can I modify my code to make these functions work concurrently, so that the bot can handle incoming messages while continuously checking for image detections in the background?

Here's my full code:

```
import asyncio
import numpy as np
from aiogram import *
import pyautogui
import cv2
import os

current_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_directory = os.path.join(current_directory, 'Images')
template_image = cv2.imread(
    image_directory + "\\image.pnh", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

bot_token = 'MY_BOT_TOKEN'
chat_id = MY_CHAT_ID
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

def template_match(template, x = 0.8):
    screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
    screenshot = np.array(screenshot)  
    gray_screenshot = cv2.cvtColor(screenshot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(gray_screenshot, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    threshold = x
    loc = np.where(res >= threshold)
    if len(loc[0]) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

@dp.message_handler()
async def handle_messages(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("I received your message.")
    # Going to add some code to handle user messages

async def image_detection():
    print("imageDetection() is executing...")
    while True:
        if(template_match(template_image)):
            screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
            screenshot.save('captured_image.jpg')
            with open('captured_image.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
                await bot.send_photo(chat_id, photo)
                await bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Image detected') # send detected image to user

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        dp.start_polling(),
        image_detection()
    )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Create two processes, one for opencv and one for aiogram.  

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=image_detection) 

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=handle_messages)

    # Start both processes.  

    p1.start()

    p2.start()
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation. You also could have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).